# Using '$' in shell

Tags: command-line

I am new to ubuntu, and tried to use [OpenFOAM](http://www.openfoam.org) Installation worked OK; after that I copy-pasted the very first example, worked also OK. but I cannot understand how.
There are funny commands like:

```
mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN
```

This creates the folder structure `/home/username/OpenFOAM/username-2.3.1/run`

Or

```
cp -r $FOAM_TUTORIALS $FOAM_RUN
```

This copies the tutorials in the above mentioned folder

What does the sign `$` do?

These commands work when copy-pasted, but I want understanding them and being able to use them later on.

Answer (score 8):

The name of a variable is a placeholder for its value, the data it holds. Referencing (retrieving) its value is called variable substitution. The $ sign helps us to get the value.

> Let us carefully distinguish between the name of a variable and its
>   value. If *variable1* is the name of a variable, then *$variable1* is
>   a reference to its value, the data item it contains, for example:

We define variable1 with a value 23:

```
$ variable1 = 23
```

To print the name of the variable (*echo* is just like a print function in the terminal):

```
$ echo variable1
variable1
```

To print the actual value saved in the variable

```
$ echo $variable1
23
```

Comment: Many thanks, I am a bit clever (or at least more informed:)  than 3 h ago:)

Answer (score 2):

Variables in your shell are marked with a `$`. I assume a path has been stored as `$FOAM_RUN`. You can see all variables in your shell by running:

```
$ env
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
GDM_LANG=en_US.utf8
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
WINDOWID=41943044
HOME=/home/orangetux
XDG_VTNR=7
SSH_AGENT_PID=1774
XDG_SEAT=seat0
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
...
```

You can see the the value of a variable by printing it:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/orangetux
```